# How to enable PHP's openssl extension to install Composer?

Tags: php, composer-php, php-openssl

I am trying to install Laravel in WAMP setup. I am getting a warning message for not enabling **openssl** which I had already done in WAMP.

Here is a screenshot of the message.

[image]

Comment: Check for the path of PHP in the environment variable `%PATH%`, maybe Composer is looking for PHP in other location instead of WampServer.

Answer (score 129):

It is possible that WAMP and Composer are using different PHP installations. Composer will use the PHP set in the `PATH` environment variable.

If you want to enable the *openssl* extension to install *Composer*, first you need to check the location of the PHP installation.

1. Open a Command Prompt, type: `echo %PATH%` then check for the location of your PHP installation.
2. Go to that location and edit the file named: `php.ini`.
3. Uncomment the line `extension=php_openssl.dll` by removing the semicolon at the beginning.

Now you are good to install Composer.

Comment: It's happen I do not have this extension on my XAMPP installation. I just added (extension=php_openssl.dll) on the php.ini and it is working downloading laravel dependencies.

Comment: when i type `echo %PATH%` I get: `C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\Sysem32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program files\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\;C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin`.. there isn't any php installed in any of those directories.. what do i do now?

Comment: wamp is using this php.ini: c:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin\php.ini but composer is using PHP from CLI, and hence it's reading this file: c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.ini (so you need to enable openssl there)

Comment: I am Using xampp, Composer giving the same open ssl missing error even after removing the ';' of openssl extension in php.ini.

Comment: Brilliant! Simple bullet point like response.. worked first time

Comment: I also had to uncomment the line `extension_dir = "ext"` in `php.ini`, but I'm using the plain PHP installation instead of WAMP.

Answer (score 64):

I had the same problem and here the solution I found, on your *php.ini* you need to do some changes:

1. `extension_dir = "ext"`
2. `extension = php_openssl.dll`

Every one here talks active the openssl extension, but in windows you need to active the extension dir too.

Comment: Men you are the only one that mentioned the `extension_dir`, you are great !

Comment: This worked for me. I had downloaded PHP directly like in this [turtorial](http://drivemarketing.ca/en/blog/installing-composer-on-windows-10/).

Answer (score 62):

I solved my problem a different way. The problem is that wamp's GUI was misleading: it claimed that I had `php_openssl` enabled.. and if I clicked on `php.ini` on the same GUI.. it actually showed that `extension=php_openssl.dll` was uncommented..

I'm not sure if i'm using the same installer version of composer of the OP, but it actually asks you at the beginning to specify the `php.exe` that you like to apply composer on (which basically ensures that no one tries to apply composer to the wrong php executable as what happened with the OP)..

The way I solved this was by going myself into the installation of php within the wamp package: `C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12` and looking `php.in` there.. when I opened it I was shocked that the line `extension=php_openssl.dll` was actually commented! I uncommented it and it worked just fine.

[image]

Comment: Thanks after having to look at this answer i figured out wamp was using 5.5.12 but i selected 5.4 directory for php.exe

Comment: In what path do the files `libeay32.dll` or `liblibcrypto-*.dll` reside? http://php.net/manual/de/openssl.installation.php

Answer (score 27):

For WAMP server, comment given by "Enrique" solved my problem.

wamp is using this *php.ini*:

```
c:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin\php.ini
```

But composer is using PHP from CLI, and hence it's reading this file:

```
c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.ini (so you need to enable openssl there)
```

For composer you will have to enable extension in

```
c:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.ini
```

Change:

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

to

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Comment: For MAMP, I had to copy the php.ini file from C:\MAMP\conf\phpx.x.x  to C:\MAMP\bin\php\phpx.x.x    (\conf\....   to  \bin\...)

Answer (score 22):

If you're doing this on Windows **without** one of the WAMP stacks, here's how to get this going

1. Download an [installation of PHP for Windows](http://windows.php.net/download/). Generally you'll want a non-thread safe install. You can use 32-bit or 64-bit builds
2. Extract the zip file somewhere. I would suggest `C:\php`. Composer's installer found it there without any additional prompting
3. The latest versions of PHP for Windows **do not come with a `php.ini` by default**. Instead, you'll see two files, as noted below. Rename one to `php.ini` or copy it into `php.ini`.

   - php.ini-development
   - php.ini-production
4. Open your `php.ini` file and remove the semicolon from this line (you might want to uncomment other things as well but this line is the only one necessary for Composer)

   ```
   ;extension=php_openssl.dll
   ```

That should be all you need to do. The Composer installer should do everything else you need from here.

Comment: This is the ONLY place online with the correct solution (for a non-WAMP) setup. Thanks!

Comment: For anyone using a newer version of PHP: this line is now ;extension=openssl

Answer (score 12):

This is an old question but I just had the same issue (with PHP7) and the solution was, in the end, pretty simple. Uncommenting the line in `php.ini` as per the other answers wasn't quite enough though. I needed to change it from:

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

to:

```
extension=ext/php_openssl.dll
```

Note the `ext` prefix. The dll already existed but was in a subfolder. After changing the config the composer installer was happy.

Answer (score 11):

You need to enable "extension=php_openssl.dll" in both files (php and apache). my pc files path are these :

1. C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13\php.ini
2. C:\wamp\bin\apache\apache2.2.22\bin\php.ini

Answer (score 7):

you need to enable the openssl extension in

```
C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.ini
```

that is the php configuration file that has it type has "configuration settings" with a driver-notepad like icon.

1. open it either with notepad or any editor,
2. search for openssl "your ctrl + F " would do.
3. there is a semi-colon before the openssl extension

   ```
   ;extension=php_openssl.dll
   ```

   remove the semi-colon and you'll have

   ```
   extension=php_openssl.dll
   ```
4. save the file and restart your WAMP server after that you're good to go.
   re-install the application again that should work.

Answer (score 6):

There are two `php.ini` files, one for development and one for production. Leave those, there is another `php.ini` file for configuration settings just above them with a gear like icon edit that.

Comment: Alternatively, mine did not have a default. Just copy/paste the prod/dev one and rename it to `php.ini`, then make the edits others have suggested here.

Answer (score 5):

After editting the "right" files (all php.ini's). i had still the issue.
My **solution** was:

1. Adding a System variable: OPENSSL_CONF

   the value of OPENSSL_CONF should be the openssl.cnf file of your current php version.

for me it was:

- C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.6.12\extras\ssl\openssl.cnf

-> Restart WAMP
-> should work now

Source: http://php.net/manual/en/openssl.installation.php

Answer (score 2):

I am using WAMP server.
Actually its files showed that openssl is opened.
But manually I went to the folder and edited `php.ini`.
Then I found it has not opened openssl.I uncommented it and it worked after after WAMP restart.

Answer (score 2):

C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.3.13

Browse to the line that reads:

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

and remove the semicolon preceding the line. Restart your WAMP server services (click in your icon tray > 'Restart All Services'

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem, but when i was lokking for php.ini and php.exe i found php.exe at C:\UwAmp\bin\php\php-5.4.15 when php.ini at C:\UwAmp\bin\apache.
I just copy php.ini at C:\UwAmp\bin\php\php-5.4.15 and Uncomment the line extension=php_openssl.dll and it fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Wamp works with another php.ini that is in C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.4.4\bin\php.ini. So you need to manualy find the correct file, that is in C:\wamp\bin\php\php5.4.12\php.ini. Uncomment the extension=php_openssl.dll line and just try to install Composer again.

Answer (score 0):

**If you still cannot solve your problem have a look at this. This might be the solution you are looking for**

There are several php.ini files in C:\wamp\bin\php\php x-y-z folder. You may find production, development and some other php.ini files. No point of editing production and development files. Find the file which is exactly as same as the below image. (You can find it. Just type php.ini in your search bar and do a search). Open the file and remove ; from extension=php_openssl.dll. Save the file and close it. Restart all services in Wampp server. Re-install your composer.

That is it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

For those who're having the same problem as I was. After doing all the solutions above, still didn't work for me. I found out that, uWamp was creating the PHP.INI file in bin/apache directory. So I had to copy the PHP.INI file into php installation directory, that is, bin/php/phpXXXX directory. This should also be where the php.exe is that you selected from the composer setup.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you compiled from source, then adding `extension=php_openssl.dll` to the php.ini file may **not work**.

To troubleshoot this, open a command prompt and type `php -i`. Scroll up to the first line, it will tell you the most recent error regarding your php.ini file.

To solve the issue, find the `php_openssl.dll` file, for me it was in the very same directory of the compilation output: 
`C:\php-sdk\bin\phpdev\vc14\x64\php-7.0.13-src\x64\Release_TS`
So just add the directory where the extension is, to the `php.ini`:

```
extension_dir = "C:\php-sdk\bin\phpdev\vc14\x64\php-7.0.13-src\x64\Release_TS"
```

Hopefully the error will be gone

Answer (score -1):

If you are using xampp .Go back to where you choose which command-line php you want to use at the beginning of your installation and select the path where your xampp folder is included.After that if your installer says youve got duplicate 'extension=php_openssl.dll' comment one ssl file in your php ini with a ';'and your installation should run smoothly.

Answer (score -1):

Well, I had to re-install the `composer` with `developer` checked and didn't get the error.