# Unable to load dynamic library openssl.so

Tags: php, macos, apache, openssl, composer-php

I just set up PHP and Apache on a Mac 10.8 localhost. So far it works fine.
I am now installing Symfony2. When I run the Composer install command, I get the following error :

```
$ curl -s http://getcomposer.org/installer | php
#!/usr/bin/env php
Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:
The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.
If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl
```

I uncommented the following line in php.ini :

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

But I still get the same error, preceded by this message :

```
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_openssl.dll' - dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_openssl.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_openssl.dll' - dlopen(/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/php_openssl.dll, 9): image not found in Unknown on line 0
```

There's no openssl.so file in my /usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/ folder indeed.
I tried reinstalling php but it made no difference. I googled for hours yet I couldn't find a way to recompile php with --with-openssl. Any help would be of great value.

Comment: Maybe you can check this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064612/how-to-enable-phps-openssl-extension-to-install-composer

Comment: Did you ensure openssl is installed?

Comment: @MarcoBernardini I am working on Mac and without MAMP which doesn't meet all my requirements. Therefore I guess the discussion you pointed out doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @JimGarrison I installed php using the liip package. It seems to me that openssl is not installed. So I tried installing php with the package from www.php.net/downloads.php, which apparently includes openssl. Yet I haven't been able to run this new php install, I can't find the PHP files on localhost (though I succeeded in locating php.ini) !

Comment: Did you check the result of phpinfo()? To get useful infos about your php installation make a page with just this line: `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` and you'll see everything about your php configuration, modules, etc.

Comment: On my previous install (using liip package) phpinfo stated that openssl support was enabled, but the Composer install command returned the above mentioned error.
As I didn't succeed in running PHP with the www.php.net/downloads.php package, I can't display phpinfo (which requires PHP to be up and running).