# OpenSSL extension is required for PHP 5 users

Tags: laravel-5

I develop a laravel app my computer using wamp server.I deploy the project into free web host. When I run this project ,it says error which is given below screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/414ae.png

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064612/how-to-enable-phps-openssl-extension-to-install-composer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find your PHP installation folder

and when you find php.ini

remove the ";" in front of:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

then restart ur php server.

Comment: Thanks for your answer but I can not configure php.ini file in free web host