# How to install composer - Missing openssl

Tags: composer-php

I have read [How to enable PHP's openssl extension to install Composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064612/how-to-enable-phps-openssl-extension-to-install-composer) and [You must enable the openssl extension to download files via https](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14291151/you-must-enable-the-openssl-extension-to-download-files-via-https)

They both state that the php file needs to uncomment `extension=php_openssl.dll` from the php.ini files which live in both these folders:

```
C:\wamp64\bin\apache\apache2.4.17
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.0
C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.16          ' I don't think I need to, but did it any way
```

I've done that, and then restarted the PC.

WAMP is running on my Windows 10 machine

The same error always shows when trying to install Composer

> Some settings on your machine make Composer unable to work properly.
>   Make sure that you fix the issues listed below and run this script again:
>
> The openssl extension is missing, which means that secure HTTPS transfers are impossible.
>     If possible you should enable it or recompile php with --with-openssl

What do I need to do to install Composer?

**Edit**

From `C:\PHP` (the PHP folder) I started a command prompt and ran `php -r "phpinfo();"`

In the results, there is the following:

> OpenSSL support => disabled (install ext/openssl)

I have followed http://php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.addtopath

Comment: make sure you're editing the correct .ini file, and dont forget to restart apache. maybe this will help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14447063/2460773

Comment: @NitsanBaleli, I'm not sure how the link you've kindly provided differs from the second file path in my post :s

Comment: Run `php -r "phpinfo();"` in the command line and make sure openssl is enabled. WAMP uses different php.ini file in console mode. If not you can find location of the used php.ini within the output of phpinfo call.

Comment: hmm, @mike, it shows  `OpenSSL support => disabled (install ext/openssl)`.. I have done http://php.net/manual/en/faq.installation.php#faq.installation.addtopath

Comment: Find the php.ini used in the command line by PHP and remove the semicolon before extension=php_openssl.dll

Comment: @mike, I have 2 files, one called `php.ini-production` and the other called `php.ini-development`. `php.ini-production` already has this, the `php.ini-development` is totally commented (every line in the file starts with `;`). Still, I removed this one comment, same issue (but thanks for staying with me)

Comment: @NitsanBaleli restarting Apache is not needed to change CLI settings as a new PHP instance is implicitly started on every CLI invocation.

Comment: @MyDaftQuestions those 2 are the blueprint samples for a typical development or production scenario. Rename the one you want (usually development) to `php.ini` to actually make PHP load it, then edit it. Currently it's not loading either of them.

Comment: Did you follow my instructions? In the phpinfo()'s output in the command line you will find the path to the USED php.ini file. `php -r "phpinfo();" | findstr Loaded`

Comment: @NielsKeurentjes, I renamed the `php.ini-production` to `php.ini` and composer is installed! Thank you, can you move your comment to an answer?

Answer (score 0):

You have multiple version of PHP installed:

1. C:\wamp64\bin\php\php7.0.0
2. C:\wamp64\bin\php\php5.6.16
3. C:\PHP

---

- The PHP version, which you run on the CLI is based on your environment PATH variable. The first PHP path wins.
- run `php --ini` on the CLI. It will show you which `php.ini` is included and also the path of PHP

  - edit this `php.ini` file and activate the `extension=php_openssl.dll`
- then run `php -m` to check, if the extension is loaded
- then run `composer`