# php composer.phar install on zend framework 3 does not working

Tags: php, zend-framework, composer-php

I'm working in Zend framework project with server Apache 2 and PHP 7 on Ubuntu 16.04.

When I run

```
php composer.phar install
```

in cmd, I get this error message:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/lib/php/20151012/php_openssl.dll' - /usr/lib/php/20151012/php_openssl.dll: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0
>   Could not open input file: composer.phar

Comment: Interesting. Now what's your question?

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064612/how-to-enable-phps-openssl-extension-to-install-composer

Comment: when I run php composer.phar install dosn't work how i can solve this problem?   i work in ubuntu 16.04 and with apache 2 php 7.0