# PHP error when creating a new symfony project using composer

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

My problem is when I create a new Symfony 3.4 project with Composer.

I will enter the following command:

> composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton projectName

When composer begins to create the project it will give me the following warnings:

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_openssl' (tried: C:\php\ext\php_openssl (The specified module could not be found.
>   ), C:\php\ext\php_php_openssl.dll (The specified module could not be found.
>   )) in Unknown on line 0
>
> Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'php_openssl' (tried: C:\php\ext\php_openssl (The specified module could not be found.
>   ), C:\php\ext\php_php_openssl.dll (The specified module could not be found.
>   )) in Unknown on line 0
>
> [Composer\Exception\NoSslException]
>     The openssl extension is required for SSL/TLS protection but is not available. If you can not enable the openssl extension, you can disable this error, at your own risk, by setting the 'disable-tls' option to true.

From my understanding, SSL is encryption for websites. At a judgment, I think the problem is composer cannot download Symfony securely.By telling me to try disabling TLS I think means trying to download Symfony insecurely since TLS is another form of encryption.

I have never had this problem with Composer before, I can not think of anything I have changed for this problem to occur.

If anyone has come across this problem or knows of any solutions that would be greatly appreciated because I cannot work on existing projects because of this.

EDIT:
The file path it is looking down is incorrect, it should check down "C:\wamp\bin\php\php7.2.1\ext" and not "C:\php\ext\" as this file path does not exist. I am unsure how to adjust this.

Comment: You need to enable the PHP openssl extension. How this is done depends on your local server.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to enable PHP's openssl extension to install Composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064612/how-to-enable-phps-openssl-extension-to-install-composer)

Comment: Apologies, I have read through the thread but my problem is slightly different I have made a further comment on the solution. @Emil

Answer (score 2):

1. Go to that location and edit the file named: `php.ini`
2. Uncomment the line `extension=php_openssl.dll` by removing the semicolon at the beginning.
3. Restart your server

Comment: I seem to be having trouble with changing the file path it is searching down. The file path "C:\php\ext\php_php_openssl.dll" is incorrect. I found the actual path but I do not know how to edit the file path.

Comment: So what is the real path of your `php_openssl.dll` file? @StevenG1

Answer (score 0):

Locate your php.ini and adjust extension_dir according to your needs. You can find more info [here](http://php.net/manual/fa/install.windows.extensions.php).