# Composer diagnose github rate limit keeps failing, using oauth tokens doesn't work either, connection times out, and download fails, what shall I do?

Tags: laravel, composer-php

I followed the official instructions to install composer, but then I could not install either laravel or any other package. The connection simply times out, the download fails, saying that it cannot download some github api file.

Answer (score 0):

I posted this question after I have found the solution because it took me almost two days to solve it. I tried disabling ipv6, switched from ubuntu to windows, but to no avail. But finally, this post gave me the answer I needed: [How to enable PHP's openssl extension to install Composer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18064612/how-to-enable-phps-openssl-extension-to-install-composer)

I wanted to link it here because you might not at first think of searching for openssl extension. But it does solve the problem, at least it did for me.

Well, it did and then it did not. It worked for a while when the light went out, which I suspect must have shutoff some firewall server.

So, in my case, what finally solved the problem was switching from my school's wifi to a mobile data connection. Then the github rate limit passed the diagnose, and all downloads run smoothly.